# Dual monitor setup is not not allowing full resolution

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, resolution, xorg

I have two monitors, one is connected via HDMI and the other one is connected via a VGA to a DVI adapter.  Both of the monitors are 21.5" and support 1920x1080.

The first monitor (HDMI) works just fine in full 1920x1080 resolution. The second monitor says that it supports only 1600x1200, which my monitor only supports 1080 so it doesn't run on it, but it runs just fine on 1600x900, this is how it looks like:

[image: pic]

I have tried to manually alter the resolution in xorg.conf but it did not work, it returned back to 1600x900.

I want to use both monitors with the same resolution (1920x1080) in Ubuntu but I don't know how.  I am using the latest drivers from the AMD website (not the beta) for my card. I have a ATI RADEON HD 7950 3GB 384 bytes GDDR5.

This is my current xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP5"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "50"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-CRT1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1920 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP5" "0-DFP5"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1920x1080"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu, all updates done.

How can I fix this resolution issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using this guy's method.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2225304

the last message:

> Heres how I did it for any ATI users in the world left with this
> problem (And possibly nvidia and intel but I cant guarantee it:
>
> 1: Go into Additional Drivers.
>
> 2: Select the X.org driver.
>
> 3: Go back into xrandr and set up your custom resolution as you would normally.
>
> 4: Impying that this worked you should now have your custom resolution
>
> 5: Go back to your fglrx ATI driver in the custom resolution.
>
> This worked for me and was able to reboot in that resolution. I hope this
> works for you too.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Arandr`:

`sudo apt-get install arandr`

or download and install from Ubuntu Apps Directory

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/arandr/

[image]

Comment: XRandR failed:
XRandR returned error code 1: xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed